# Vim line completion has stopped working

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

In Vim, a very useful keyboard shortcut is <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> (that's a lowercase L) which will complete the entire line you're typing based on lines in all open buffers. My linewise completion has stopped working.

When I type (in insert mode) <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> it correctly shows me `^X Mode (...^L)` in my status line, but when I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> Vim just beeps at me and outputs nothing.

I have 54 plugins and update my `.vimrc` often. How can I debug this shortcut? Is there a way to see what a double stroke motion is mapped to?

Comment: See if anything is mapped to `<c-x>` with `:verbose imap <c-x>`, If something doesn't come up, is your vimrc in version control? If it is just revert back to a known good commit. If it isn't binary search your plugins/vimrc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was because I was using the software [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en) which ironically is designed to give you Vi mode in various parts of OSX. The specific setting I had enabled was `ctrl-hjkl` in any inputs would map to up/down/left/right. I discovered this by running `vim -u NONE` to run Vim without plugins, and as it still presented the error, I realized the problem lied outside of Vim.